# Set the limit in Queue

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to set a limit on my Queue. You can find below the implementation of the Queue class.

So, in short, I want to write in Queue in one thread until the limit and then wait for the free space. And the second thread read the Queue and do some operations with the data that it received.

```
int main()
{
    //loop that adds new elements to the Queue. 
     thread one(buildQueue, input, Queue); 

    loop{
        obj = Queue.pop()
        func(obj) //do some math
    }



}
```

So the problems is that the Queue builds until the end, but I want to set only 10 elements, for example. And program should work like this:

1. Check whether free space in Queue is available.

   1. If there is no space - wait.
   2. Write in the Queue until the limit.

---

**Class Queue**

```
template <typename T> class Queue{
private:
    const unsigned int MAX = 5;
    std::deque<T>           newQueue;
    std::mutex              d_mutex;
    std::condition_variable d_condition;
public:
    void push(T const& value)
    {

        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->d_mutex);
            newQueue.push_front(value);
        }
        this->d_condition.notify_one();
    }
    T pop()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->d_mutex);
        this->d_condition.wait(lock, [=]{ return !this->newQueue.empty(); });
        T rc(std::move(this->newQueue.back()));
        this->newQueue.pop_back();
        return rc;
    }

    unsigned int size()
    {
        return newQueue.size();
    }

    unsigned int maxQueueSize()
    {
        return this->MAX;
    }

};
```

I'm pretty new in threads program so that I could misunderstand the conception. That is why different hints are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should have researched the Queue class in the [MSDN website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-2). It provides extensive information revolving methods included with Queue. However, to answer your question specifically, to set a queue with a specific capacity, it would be the following:

```
Queue(int capacity)
```

where it is Type `System::int32` capacity is the initial number of elements in the queue. Then, your queue will be filled until the limit. The issue is, the queue will not "stop" once its filled. It will start to allocate more memory as that is its nature so in your threaded (or multithreaded by the sounds of it), you must make sure to take care of the realoc-deallocation of the queue memory based on timing. You should be able to determine the milliseconds needed to fill your queue with the desired capacity and read the queue, meanwhile clearing the queue. Likewise, you can copy the queue contents to a 1D array and do a full queue clear using `MyQueue->Clear()`without having to read queue elements 1 by one (if timing and code complexity is an issue).